# Active tab fixed to the left in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, productivity-power-tools

I have recently installed a few tools in Visual Studio, such as Resharper and Power tools.

And now my Visual Studio seems to be "*smarter*" than before. Whenever I switch to another tab, this active tab will be set as the first tab.

How can I disable this behaviour?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue after a fresh reinstall of VS 2015 with ReSharper and Productivity tools. Trying to find the setting ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The active tab behavior also changed for me randomly after restarting VS. This is how I fixed it (with Productivity Power Tools extension installed) :

Tools -> Options -> Productivity Power tools -> Custom document well -> Sorting -> Uncheck Most recently used

Comment: A hotfix for this default was released on July 25.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d?SRC=VSIDE