# Active tab in Visual Studio moves left?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, productivity-power-tools

In Visual Studio 2015 Pro, all of a sudden whichever editor window I have active, its tab moves to the leftmost position.

It must have been some key combination I hit and I can't figure out how to turn it off. I have power tools installed but haven't seen this as an option before. I just mention it because I know it has options for coloring/sorting tabs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391613/active-tab-fixed-to-the-left-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is a result of the new "Sort by Most Recently Used" option added to Productivity Power Tools in July 2016.

This feature is enabled by default, but can be disabled in Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools > Custom Document Well > Sorting: Most recently used.

Comment: This was addressed with a hotfix disabling this as default on Jul 25.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d?SRC=VSIDE